# RARE II Roadless Data

Tags: data

I am looking for data showing RARE II Roadless Areas on USFS Lands.

RARE II was an early inventory of Roadless areas that was completed in the late 70s.  This dataset is different than areas that are currently recognized as

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=2dd4cfcf14e34bc8bd9d3bd7e13b1091?

Comment: yes, these are areas currently defined as roadless areas.  It is indicated that RARE II was used to build this dataset but they are essentially different